# Partial updates/recreation of Shield UI Chart ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, shieldui

Is it possible to partially refresh/recreate a Shield UI ASP.NET chart? What I need is to show a couple of series but refresh them at different rates; some of the series will refresh every couple of seconds. Others will update much slower. I tried different approaches but none has given any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure partial refresh or recreation of a Shield UI Chart is not possible. This is at least because at the time of the chart recreation the chart itself is disposed of and than created back again.

However in terms of functionality partial or asynchronous refresh is possible by splitting the two processes: data acquisition and its visualization on the chart.  For instance You may use a couple of functions with different execute intervals to get the data from your sources. Than another function (probably with refresh interval shorter or equal to the refresh interval of the fastes of the other functions) will recreate the chart using the

```
.destroy();
```

method and will show the data.